# What kind of connector do I need to splice this cable?

Tags: connector

The LCD display on my range hood started to go bad with dead pixels. The manufacturer sent me a replacement part (see photo). I thought swapping out the part would be trivial. The problem is that the connector is way out of reach; I'd have to remove the entire blower assembly to be able to disconnect the old cable and attach the cable of the new part.

So I thought it would be easier to take the cable of the new part and attach the new part to the cable of the old part. Then I ran into my second obstacle: it doesn't look like the connector is meant to come off. The contacts to the wires appear soldered onto the board (see second photo). That's probably why I was not able to detach the plastic part off.

So I'm stuck. As a last ditch effort, I'm thinking that I could cut the cable, strip the wires, and put on a new connector to attach part of the old cable to the new cable. I.e., make 2 cuts and splice old cable to new.

Is this a good idea? If so, what kind of male/female connector do I need? (I'm a software guy so this is all new to me.) With some tips to point me in the right direction, I can do more research online. Thanks!

[image: range hood LCD display and controller]

[image: cable connects to controller]

[image: back of component]

Comment: There's something I don't yet understand. The last picture shows clearly a *connector* which can be removed, easily (assuming no obstructions.) It's mounted in a clear plastic enclosure (with a stretch of meaning for that word.) It even looks as though you can slide it off, though I cannot see the backside to know. So the only issue I can imagine here is that you can't seem to remove that connector for reasons I can't fathom yet. Is it blocked somehow?? Can't you just unscrew the housing?? Or is it the other end you are worried over?

Comment: @jonk, I added a photo of the backside that shows the leads are soldered to the component. Before I took it apart, I thought the connector would come right off, too. You can see a small gap. That's me trying to pull it off, but that's as far as it will slide. I was afraid if I forced it further I would break it.

Comment: The 3rd picture helps. Unless they went to a lot of trouble to make a "false" connector, that's a real connector. And now it really looks easy to remove the connector. Just use your finger nails to slide it backwards and off the pins, then work it out through the hole in the back. There is no possible way I'd let that beast get the better of me. Use a screwdriver if you need to. To confirm it moves, just observe the bare connector pins changing their exposure. If you can press that connector back on, then it is a connector. It's just a matter of removing it.

Comment: The 2nd picture clearly shows that the white connector is stuck against two side 'rails' of the clear housing. What you need to do is push the printed circuit board out of the clear housing, then you can unplug the white connector. That's all.

Comment: Thanks @jonk and @JvO! I got it off. See below.

Comment: @Techmec Good to hear. It looked relatively uncomplicated. But I understand that without any experience at all you could feel a little uncertain. Best wishes on the rest that's ahead of you.

Answer (score 0):

A really primitive way, I don't know if it's recommended, you could cut the cabls in half and solder each wire to it's matching one
Edit: meaning no special connectors just solder them

Comment: And then cover each joint with heat-shrink tubing.  Make sure to thread a bit of tubing on one side, before soldering!

Comment: @SimonB put the tubing before soldering  not like how I do it always, after the soldering

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all who responded, particularly @jonk and @JvO. This photo is the picture of success. Once you gave me assurance that it was a removable connector, I used force and got it to clear the side rails.

Now I need to disconnect the old part. That will be a pain since it will be awkward without a flat surface and hanging off the range hood.

[image]